# Oracle: how to check if system date not in working hours

Tags: sql, oracle

how to check if system date within Friday 5pm and Monday 8am in oracle sql. I want to implement a trigger to add update restrictions on a table.

Comment: To check day of week - `WeekDay(myDate)`, To get hour - `Extract(Hour from myDate)`

Comment: this did not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a working solution. it may help to someone.

```
IF to_char(sysdate, 'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') IN ('SAT','SUN') 
        THEN
            raise_application_error(-20000, 'message...');
        
    ELSIF to_char(sysdate, 'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') IN ('FRI') AND to_number(to_char(sysdate, 'hh24MIss')) > 170000
        THEN
            raise_application_error(-20000, 'message...');
            
    ELSIF to_char(sysdate, 'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') IN ('MON') AND to_number(to_char(sysdate, 'hh24MIss')) < 80000
        THEN
            raise_application_error(-20000, 'message...');
    END IF;
```

Comment: Did you mean < 80000 in the second condition? Or did you mean 9 a.m. in the problem description? (You wrote 8 a.m. but in the code you compare to 9 a.m.)

Comment: updated above. it should be < 80000. thanks @mathguy

Answer (score 0):

We can use the following query to find out whether or not we are between Monday day 1 at 7 am : 107 and Friday at 17 : 517.

```
select 
  case 
    when to_char(sysdate, 'DHH24',
 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') 
    between 107 and 517 then 'week'
    else 'weekend' end "rate"
from dual;
```

Comment: Day number is NLS-dependent, so this may not always do what you expect.

Comment: This does not work as you would expect as the `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` session parameter does not control the output of `TO_CHAR` when you supply the `D` format model. It is controlled by the `NLS_TERRITORY` session parameter and if you try setting that as the 3rd argument of `TO_CHAR` then you will get the error `ORA-12702: invalid NLS parameter string used in SQL function` [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=3c31899ece270eff18921fe7f9cbbe27).

Comment: @MTO Thank you. That complicates things. I didn't realize there could be 4 different ideas of the first day of the week. I think the best thing is to ask the user to test for their system settings and modify or use another solution if it's not good for them.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it independent of the NLS settings by comparing the current date to the start of the current ISO week (always midnight on Monday):

```sql
IF SYSDATE - TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') < 8/24
THEN
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Before 08:00 Monday');
ELSIF SYSDATE - TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') > 4 + 17/24
THEN
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'After 17:00 Friday');
END IF;
```

Or, using `INTERVAL` literals:

```sql
IF SYSDATE < TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') + INTERVAL '8' HOUR
THEN
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Before 08:00 Monday');
ELSIF SYSDATE > TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') + INTERVAL '4 17:00:00' DAY TO SECOND
THEN
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'After 17:00 Friday');
END IF;
```

Or, as a single check with bounds that correspond to the times of day then:

```sql
IF (SYSDATE - TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW')) DAY TO SECOND
      NOT BETWEEN INTERVAL '0 08:00:00' DAY TO SECOND
              AND INTERVAL '4 17:00:00' DAY TO SECOND
THEN
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Outside working hours.');
END IF;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=0071795368edf8d15ff4b2198b776a9a)*

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a single, closed-form computation. You are "within working hours" (by your definition) if the time-of-week is between Monday 08:00 and Friday 17:00. This is the same as "sysdate" - 8 hours is between Monday 00:00 and Friday 09:00. This also means that you are "on a weekend" if and only if the time-of-week of "sysdate - 8 hours" is strictly greater than Friday 09:00.

All of this can be expressed easily using date and interval arithmetic:

```
if ((sysdate - interval '8' hour) - trunc(sysdate - interval '8' hour, 'iw')
   ) day to second > interval '4 9:00:00' day to second
then .......
end if;
```

Comment: question is about finding the weekend and trigger.